# Custom Search Suggestion not showing up in Android Application

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I tried the following guide from Google: [Adding Custom Suggestion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html). I got the searching feature of my app working but I can't get the search suggestions to appear.

If I type something when the SearchView is active, it doesn't show any suggestions at all. For example I got 3 items which contains the world `Hello`. When I type in hello, I expect there will be a listview of some sort that will appear below the SearchView. There isn't. Is it because I don't have much content on the database yet?

So here's what I got so far. If you can point out what I missed that would be great!

Android Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.neonwarge.android.note"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:name=".NoteApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.HomeScreenActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>            

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.NoteActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_label_note"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.HomeScreenActivity" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.NoteSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/activity_label_notesettings" >

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.NoteActivity" />

        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.SearchResultActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_result"
            android:launchMode="singleTop">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.HomeScreenActivity"/>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="com.neonwarge.android.note.activities.SearchResultActivity"/>

        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".receivers.NoteAlarmReceiver" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.neonwarge.android.note.providers.NoteProvider"
            android:authorities="com.neonwarge.android.note.providers.NoteProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:multiprocess="true" />       

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Content Provider:

```
    mUriMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY , SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY , NOTE_SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS);

...

@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String whereClause, String[] selection,String sortorder) 
{
    (...)   
    case NOTE_SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:

            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG , "NoteProvider.query() : search suggest enabled...");
            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG , "URI : " + uri.toString());
            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG , "Where " + whereClause);
            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG , "Searching for : " + selection[0]);

            projection = 
                new String[]
                {
                      "rowid as " + NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry._ID
                    , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.COLUMN_SHORT_NOTE + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1
                    , NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.COLUMN_LONG_NOTE + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2
                };

            cursor = db.query(NoteDatabaseHelper.NoteEntry.VIRTUAL_TABLE_NAME , projection , whereClause , selection, null, null, null);
            break;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown uri " + uri);
    }

    return cursor;
}

...
@Override
public String getType(Uri uri) 
{
    Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG , "NoteProvider.getType() : called.");
    switch(mUriMatcher.match(uri))
    {
        case NOTE_SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS:
            Log.i(NoteApplication.TAG , "NoteProvider.getType(): type: NOTE_SEARCH_SUGGESTIONS");
            return SearchManager.SUGGEST_MIME_TYPE;

        default:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("NoteProvider.getType(): Unknown URL : " + uri);
    }
}
...
```

Searchable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"    
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.neonwarge.android.note.providers.NoteProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"
    android:searchSuggestSelection="ShortNote MATCH ? and LongNote MATCH ?">
</searchable>
```

I inflated the options menu layout from the activity's fragment:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,  inflater);
    inflater.inflate(mIsOnSearchMode? R.menu.fragment_search_result : R.menu.fragment_note_list, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(new ComponentName(getActivity().getPackageName() , SearchResultActivity.class.getName())));

    searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            null,
            new String[]{SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 , SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2},
            new int[]{android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1},
            0));

    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
}
```

I had the SearchableDictionary sample loaded in my workspace and I am confident I got every spot accounted for. Maybe I am expecting something wrong here? Is the list that shows the suggestion should require an adapter? Because I have provided one and it is still not showing. Or maybe I need a million content before the suggestion works. Also, I just reused my existing content provider, do I have to use another provider?

Please let me know what I missed.

Comment: you dont need custom ContentProvider, searchable.xml, manifest meta-datas etc, see: http://codeshare.io/ybHpq

Comment: Then what do I need?

Comment: 15 lines of code i posted in the link ? did you see my link ?

Comment: Oh yes I saw that, I have question regarding that, why do you need to rerun the cursor the second time. The ContentProvider has already done this for me. The system called my ContentProvider thereby returning the cursor with the relevant suggestion. Then it stops there. If I took your path, because ultimately, I will be making my own Adapter which will require cursor as its argument. I don't know how the system will pass in the cursor to my custom adapter or if this supposedly the right thing to do, given it is not even mentioned in the documents.

Comment: Your approach seems to look like a hack to me, which will be my last course action if everything else fails. First, this is custom suggestions, of course you need a content provider. Searchable not needed? That's the point of the question, I am doing a search suggestion. I definitely need the searchable.xml file. The manifest file is also needed since I have to identify which activity needs to react on the search action.

Comment: i am also using custom SimpleCursorAdapter so whats the deal ? did my 15 lines of code run or not?

Comment: so tell me why i posted that code? the code that is not working? what would be the reason for that?

Comment: also, is `setSuggestionsAdapter` a hack? so why is it in the public API?

Comment: Of course it is on the API. But your suggested code will not work on my situation. I am so sorry. Please check my own answer.

Comment: what will not work? any reason for that? i dont see anything in your answer why you cannot return your data in `runQueryOnBackgroundThread` method

Comment: It will not work because let me be frank, that is the answer to the wrong question. Where I was wrong is this line on the searchable file: `android:searchSuggestSelection=ShortNote MATCH ? and LongNote MATCH ?` It should have been like the answer I posted. Thanks anyways. In fact, I get your point, and almost went there if I don't have any choice, I just didn't give up on this because I am almost 99% done implementing it as the guide suggested. I knew there something wrong, something minute. Something I missed. Now I can continue on developing the search features of my app from this.

Comment: I took a closer look into the logs and notice something strange, though the log did not threw any error on faulty SQL, I notice my SQL syntax is not correct for my vtable.

I don't understand why you are forcing your code on my work. It is not a silver bullet. It will work if I did it your way but its not the best in my situation. Notice I didn't -1 your answer. You technically can't do solution base on code even though you followed it 'CONCEPTUALLY'. Sometimes there are some questions not requiring code as answers but rather technical explanation why it didn't work.

Comment: i have no idea what you are talking about: there is absolutely no difference if you return the Cursor from your ContentProvider#query or CursorAdapter#runQueryOnBackgroundThread, the difference is that your code has 100 lines of code: (custom ContentProvider, searchable.xml, changes in the manifest etc) while mine has 15, the choice is yours

Comment: We're arguing now. No, what you are saying is to destroy the entire content provider my app is relying on for information. I cannot take it down because it too long. In fact is not even long. Other app should have the ability to query my app for information which if I didn't use the content provider, will no be possible anyways. The topic here is not whether the code is long or not. I don't even know why it is even brought up. +1 still. Thanks anyways. 

Also, you tiptoeing, why not have the audacity to post your answer? Clearly my post has syntax error. You providing me with optimization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very very small gotcha. I typed in the 'WRONG' sql syntax for querying the virtual table!

I originally typed it like this: `"ShortNote MATCH ? and LongNote MATCH ?"` This is wrong, as my table where not named as ShortNote and LongNote. I should have used this syntax instead:

`NAME_OF_FTS3_TABLE match ?`

I have misconceived the `android:searchSuggestSelection` and forgotten I was using the FTS3 table for looking for some data, mistakenly querying it like it is a normal table.

What I did is I simply provided a non-null value for the `android:searchSuggestSelection` and handle the whereClause myself in the ContentProvider and the list of relevant suggestion now appears below the search widget/search dialog.

Thank you!